# Getting a distinct count by year from an access database

Tags: css, database, ms-access

I'm very rusty with my SQL so this might be not so complicated but I just can't seem to be able to crack it.

I have a database with two tables - one containing details of patients and one of visits each patient has had. Patient_ID is the unique identifier for a patient and is used in the Visits table and I'm trying to pull the number of distinct patients and the total number of visits they've had (i.e. Patient A has visited 3 times in 2018)

I'm trying to get a Total count of the Distinct individual patients who have visited a centre per YEAR (field in Visits table), and also see information about the patient from the Patients table (gender, country, etc).

I've tried several count and distinct functions but can't get anything to work. The below is one of the last attempts but the distinct function doesn't actually show distinct values (am I doing something wrong with it?) in this scenario. It does work in other queries... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Visits.Patient_ID, Patient.Gender, Patient.Village, Visits.Months_Of_Visit, Visits.Year
FROM Visits
INNER JOIN Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID=Visits.Patient_ID
WHERE Year='2018';
```

Expected result:

Unique Patient Id, Patient Gender, Patient Village PER month and PER Year.

Comment: Have you tried the “GROUP BY” clause?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of times each patient visited each village/month/year:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountVisits, Visits.Patient_ID, Gender, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year]
FROM Visits
INNER JOIN Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID=Visits.Patient_ID
GROUP BY Patient_ID, Gender, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year];
```

If you want the number of DISTINCT patients per village/month/year:

Query1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Visits.Patient_ID, Gender, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year]
FROM Visits
INNER JOIN Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID=Visits.Patient_ID;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountPerVillage, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year] 
FROM Query1 GROUP BY Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year];
```

All in one:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountPerVillage, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year] 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Visits.Patient_ID, Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year]
      FROM Visits INNER JOIN Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID=Visits.Patient_ID) AS Query1 
GROUP BY Village, Months_Of_Visit, [Year];
```

Since Year is a reserved word (it is an intrinsic function), enclose in [ ] or include the table name prefix in the field reference.